# implicit differentiation computation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I am having troubles isolating and solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$,

$\sin(x+y)=xy$

$\cos(x+y)(1+\frac{dy}{dx})= x\frac{dy}{dx} + y$

What would be the next few step to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: High School algebra disguised: rearrange to find an equation $dy/dx = something$

Comment: If it helps, write a completely different variable, e.g., $D$ for $dy/dx$, then use basic algebra to solve$$\cos(x+y)\left(1+D\right)= xD + y$$for $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\cos(x+y)\left(1+ \frac{dy}{dx}\right)= x\frac{dy}{dx} + y \qquad \longleftarrow \text{ error: You need $y$ here, not $x$.}
$$
Expand:
$$
\cos(x+y)\cdot1 + \cos(x+y)\frac{dy}{dx} = x\frac{dy}{dx} + y
$$
Transpose:
$$
\cos(x+y)\frac{dy}{dx} - x\frac{dy}{dx} = \cos(x+y)\cdot1 + y
$$
Factor
$$
(\cos(x+y) - x) \frac{dy}{dx} = \cos(x+y)\cdot1 + y
$$
Then  divide both sides by $\cos(x+y) - x$.

Comment: on the first line, can you explain why it would be x.dy/dx + y?

Comment: @Cheng : Product rule: $$\begin{align} \frac d{dx}(xy) & = x\frac d {dx} y + y \frac d{dx} x \\[12pt] & = x \frac {dy}{dx} + y. \end{align}$$ ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that you already know it, the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) is very useful.

In you case, consider the function $$F=\sin(x+y)-xy=0$$ Computing each derivative, considering that the other variable is a constant, gives $$F'_x=\cos(x+y)-y$$ $$F'_y=\cos(x+y)-x$$ $$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=-\frac{\cos(x+y)-y}{\cos(x+y)-x}$$